# how to retrieve only time from this date in R :1904-01-21 03:18:35

Tags: r

I subtracted two dates in excel and forma the difference as hh:mm:ss and showing correctli in excel file , however while importing it changes to 1904-01-21 03:18:35 .

how can get back time only from this in R

needs accuaate time as needed

Answer (score 1):

We could use `format` after converting to Datetime

```
format(as.POSIXct(df1$Date), "%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @akrun's answer, there's a shorthand for the time portion of a date, `%T`

```
strftime(as.POSIXct(c("1904-01-21 03:18:35")), format="%T")
[1] "03:18:35"
```